# Error loading the keras package in R studio

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am using R4.0.1 and Rstudio1.3.959  on windows 10. I have installed tensor flow:

```
install.packages("tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(method = "conda", conda_python_version = 3.6)
```

I checked the installation success by:

```
library(tensorflow)
tf$constant("Hellow Tensorflow")
```

Output: Tensor("Const:0", shape=(), dtype=string)

```
tf$constant(1.5)
```

Output: Tensor("Const_1:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)

I further checked by:

```
tf_config()
```

Output:
TensorFlow v1.13.2 ()
Python v3.6 (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe)

From here it seems the tensor flow is installed properly and is working fine.
However, I faced problems in loading Keras library. I  did the following:

```
install.packages("keras")
library(keras)
```

As I load the library, it gives the following error

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘keras’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'keras', details:
  call: py_module_import(module, convert = convert)
  error: ImportError: cannot import name 'swish'

Detailed traceback: 
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\keras\activations\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import swish
```

Since the  keras package could not be loaded I cannot run the following code

```
install_keras(method = "conda")
```

I could get additional information as below:

```
library(reticulate)
> py_discover_config("keras")
python:         C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  7 2020, 19:46:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.18.1
```

I could also see that default python version in use as:

```
Sys.which("python")
                                                                 python 
"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\R-MINI~1\\envs\\R-RETI~1\\python.exe"
```

I would be grateful if anyone can solve this installation issue. Thanks

Comment: you lack swish python module in conda env. Try activating conda env, i think you can do that via `conda activate r-reticulate` where (r-reticulate) is the name of theconda env that keras calls (could be different check with `conda env list`, and once activated do the classic `pip install swish`.

Comment: @JacobJacox how can i do this within R studio?

Comment: Further i did this: pip install swish , i get following info:
Requirement already satisfied: swish in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from swish) (2.22.0) .  Then i tried loading library (keras), still gives the same error. I notice that the path of swishis different than that of tensorflow.

Comment: You have to do that via conda prompt. Any reason why you are using TF 1.13?

Comment: I have done like this: install_tensorflow(method = "conda", conda_python_version = 3.6,
+                    version = "2.2.0") but still it show as:     tf_config():
TensorFlow v1.13.2 ()
Python v3.6 (C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe)

Comment: I have written the answer since it was to big for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit different but I find it easier to hand manage dependent env. So you can open conda prompt and execute:

```
conda create -n env_name python=3.6 tensorflow
```

Then in R before you do anything call

```
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
use_condaenv(condaenv = "env_name",required = T)
```

By default you wil get TF 2.xx, you can specify that in conda env.

EDIT: For TF gpu you need to specify `conda create -n env_name python=3.6 tensorflow-gpu` and you will get CUDa and CUDNN if you have GPU on your PC.

Answer (score 2):

I am a Windows 10 User and I encountered the same issue today. After checking multiple posts, the below steps worked for me.

1. Update R to the latest 4.1.2 version. R Studio might say that R is up to date (which happened to me today), but it may not be.
   `install.packages("installr")`
   `library(installr)`
   `updateR()`
2. Update Rcpp, jsonlite, and curl packages even if they claim to be up to date.
   `install.packages("Rcpp")`
   `install.packages("jsonlite")`
   `install.packages("curl")`
3. Start a **Fresh** R session.
4. Run the below commands to install, reticulate, tensorflow, and keras from github:
   `devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")`
   `devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")`
   `devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")`
5. Run the below commands (Some of them may be redundant if preceding ones include the functionalities. Entering them here anyway as it could help.).
   `library(keras)`
   `install_keras()`
   `library(reticulate)`
   `library(tensorflow)`
6. Test TensorFlow installation with the command below:
   `tf$constant("Hello World!")`

If you get the below output, you're there. There could be some text before the output (ignore them).
`tf.Tensor(b'Hello World!', shape=(), dtype=string)`

When running a DNN or RNN, after installing the packages, calling just `library(keras)` shoudl be adequate.

Have fun!